# modprobe.d error on boot, ignoring bad

Tags: linux, arch-linux, modprobe

Hi I get this error at boot:

```
libkmod: kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/acpi-call.conf line 2: ignoring bad
```

on my arch linux thinkpad. Here's the thing: I deleted that file about two weeks ago, my modprobe.d directory is empty. So where is this error message coming from?

Also please note that this error msg seems somewhat chopped off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

Most likely you have a stale
[initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk)
and need to run this command (or similar) before changes in `/etc/modprobe.d`
will take effect:

```
sudo mkinitcpio -p linux
```

### Long answer

I used to think that when I edited a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`
the changes would take effect as soon as I either
(a) reloaded the module with `modprobe` or (b) rebooted.
But that's not generally true for reboots;
in most cases, the image in `/boot/` has to regenerated first.
On Ubuntu, it looks like this when the package manager does it:

```
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-48-generic
```

For a Debian-based distribution, this is handled by
[`update-initramfs`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.8.en.html)
from the
[`initramfs-tools` package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/initramfs-tools),
which is mostly a bunch of shell scripts that eventually call `cpio`.
The typical update command looks like this:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Arch Linux has its [own bunch of shell scripts](https://git.archlinux.org/mkinitcpio.git/) that eventually call `cpio`,
the main one being
[mkinitcpio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio).

I haven't used Arch Linux and don't have a virtual machine to try this out on,
but the [Arch wiki says](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio)
these are the usual options:

```
mkinitcpio -p linux
```

The wiki also suggests this command to inspect the contents:

```
lsinitcpio /boot/initramfs-linux.img
```

Personally, I find it easy to forget
the additional step of regenerating the image,
and there are many other folks who've had similar experiences:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424599/is-update-initramfs-u-needed-after-adding-or-removing-a-module-with-modprobe

https://askubuntu.com/questions/51321/modules-loading-despite-being-added-to-the-blacklist

https://askubuntu.com/questions/290884/blacklist-conf-ignoring-bad-line-boot-prompt

https://askubuntu.com/questions/817682/error-in-blacklist-conf-file-ignoring-bad-line-starting-with

https://askubuntu.com/questions/504593/ubuntu-update-caused-system-to-freeze-on-boot-at-purple-screen-recovery-mode-fa

https://askubuntu.com/questions/689277/parsing-error-in-blacklist-framebuffer-conf-occurring-at-boot

https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/bidhsl/module_blacklist_not_working_mkinitcpio/